# openapi-generator-maven-plugin and Java generics

Tags: java, generics, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I think it is a simple question: I am using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin 5.1.0` to generate java code. I would like to have a property with type `Foo<Bar>`. We use a `swagger.json` file for the DTO definition and the rest of the configuration is in a `pom.xml`.

How can I do that?

For example, here is a snippet of the `swagger.json` file:

```
      "FooBarDto" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "fooBar" : {
            "type": "FooOfBar"
          },
...
```

In the `pom.xml`, I have defined the `typeMapping` and `importMapping`:

```
...
                            <typeMappings>
                                <typeMapping>FooOfBar=Foo&lt;Bar&gt;</typeMapping>
                            </typeMappings>
                            <importMappings>
                                <importMapping>Foo&lt;Bar&gt;=com.company.Foo</importMapping>
                                <importMapping>Bar=com.company.Bar</importMapping>
                             </importMappings>

...
```

With this, I have the property generated correctly but `Bar` is not imported.

What is the right way to do that?